# IE9 :hover Glitch

Tags: css, background, hover, internet-explorer-9

I have some really odd behavior surfacing with IE9, :hover, and the CSS background property.

It's almost as if the hover and non-hover properties swap when they aren't supposed to (In other words, the hover properties become the non-hover properties). I was testing just with a background color, as well as an SVG gradient. Here's the test code (with the SVG code commented out).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .highlights {           
        background:black;

        /* SVG background gradient for #0791F3 to #068CE0 */    
        /*
        background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9ImczMDkiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+CjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwNzkxRjMiIG9mZnNldD0iMCIvPjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwNjhDRTAiIG9mZnNldD0iMSIvPgo8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50Pgo8cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2czMDkpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
        */

    }


    .highlights:hover {
        background:gray;

        /* SVG background gradient for #0064ff to #0051ff */
        /*
        background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imc0NDEiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+CjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwMDY0RkYiIG9mZnNldD0iMCIvPjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMwMDUxRkYiIG9mZnNldD0iMSIvPgo8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50Pgo8cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2c0NDEpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
        */

    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="highlights">
    <h3 class="title" style="color:#FED704">The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog</h3>
    <p style="color:white;">This is smaller text</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[edit]: Video of the odd behavior (remember, the background should appear gray on a hover): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8D4Oj25bPlg

Comment: It's correct for me, both for the solid colors and the SVG gradients. http://jsfiddle.net/FGqZe

Comment: It seems to work fine through that webapp, but not when it's a native htm file.

Comment: I've updated IE. I got version 9.0.8112.16421 (update version 9.0.3) now. It's still working as it should...

Comment: Same version here. What sorts of plugins/addons/accelerators do you have endabled? All I have enabled is adobe flash, adobe pdf helper, java, spybot SD-IE protection, and classic explorer bar.

Comment: Long list. I disabled all. No change.

Comment: Also works ok for me. Try to disable all those addons.

Comment: I noticed that in rare cases, the :hover effect operates normally for a short time, but if you either start moving the mouse sideways within the div, or move the mouse on and off of it reasonably quickly, the glitch starts occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software rendering was not enabled. As soon as I enabled it, the issue vanished.

Internet Options > "Advanced tab" > check "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering"